# foreach only inserting one record? Cant see the error?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Trying to get this to allow for more then 1 check box to be selected.

**Form**

```
          <fieldset>                
            <legend>Rooms</legend>
                <ol>
                    <li>
                        <label for =youthCafe>Youth Cafe</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="1" ><br>
                        <label for =inkwellMain>Inkwell Main</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="2"><br>
                        <label for =inkwellSmall>Inkwell Small</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="3"><br>
                        <label for =kitchen>Kitchen</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="4"><br>
                        <label for =outsideCatering>Outside Catering</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="roomid[]" value="5"><br>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </fieldset>
```

**PHP**

```
        mysql_select_db('eydg');
        $query = "insert into orders (customerNo) 
        values ($customerNo)";                  
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        $query = "select * from orders where customerNo = '$customerNo'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $bookingNo= $row['bookingNo'];

        if ( isset($_POST['roomid']) ){
            foreach( $_POST['roomid'] as $value ){ 
                $query = "insert into bookings (bookingNo,roomNo) 
                values ('$bookingNo','$value')"; 

                $result = mysql_query($query);
            }
        }
```

At the moment it will only allow for 1 selection to be added to the database. They all work on their own but if more then 1 is selected then it only inserts the 1st one.

Really cant see what is wrong with it.

Thanks

Comment: @Feroz I have added a little bit more so you have a better scope.

Comment: As mentioned by @MakKrnic Please provide output of `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST['roomid'])`

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, but I can't comment yet.

How many checkboxes have you checked?
Most browsers do not submit unchecked checkboxes.

Also, please provide output of `var_dump($_POST)` or `var_dump($_POST['roomid'])`

Comment: It's should've been a comment as you noted but it's a good point

Answer (score 0):

Note :

> the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed
>   in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
>   used.

You code is ok for me.

I advise you to use xdebug to watch your code running, this will clearly tell you where is the trouble.

But a first step can be to see what this code returns :

```
foreach( $_POST['roomid'] as $key => $value ){

    echo "\n<br>\n<br>array key=" . $key . ' : value=' . $value;
    $query = "insert into bookings (bookingNo,roomNo) values ('$bookingNo','$value')";
    echo "\n<br>query" . ' : ' . $query;
    $result = mysql_query($query, $link);
    if(!$result){
        echo "\n<br><h1>Error : " . mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) . '</h1>';
    }

}
```

Here **$link** is the var holding you connection. So replace this variable before running this code.